# Language settings in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am running Chrome on a Windows 10 desktop.  Recently when I go into gmail or Google Drive, the page gets displayed largely in Bangla.  I have the option of translating the page to English, which works ok, but has to be done every time on each page.  The Chrome settings have language set to English, and non Google pages display fine in English.  There must be another setting somewhere, but I've no idea where.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the Chrome user profile? Is the computer managed by a group policy, in other words is this connected to a company network, managed by an IT Administrator.  You can [edit] your question to include this vital information

Comment: Are you signed-in to google?

Comment: Did you try this: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your google account might be set to Bangla? This is taken from google's help pages and the relevant headings are in English, not sure what the translations will be in Bangla but hope it helps!

**To change the language for your whole google account:**

1 - Open your Google Account at https://myaccount.google.com/. You might need to sign in.

2 - Click Data & personalization.

3 - Scroll down to the General preferences for the web​ panel.

4 - Click Language.

5 - Select Edit.

6 - Choose your language from the dropdown box, and click Select.

7 - If you understand multiple languages, select Add another language.
Once you've changed your language preferences, close and reopen your browser.

**OR:
To change the language for your Gmail:**

1 - Open Gmail.

2 - In the top right, click Settings (the gear icon)

3 - Click Settings.

4 - In the "Language" section, pick a language from the drop-down menu.

5 - At the bottom of the page, click Save Changes.

**To Change the language for your google drive:**

1 - Open Google Drive using drive.google.com

2 - Click on the gear wheel icon in the upper left.

3 - Select Settings.

4 - Next to Language, select Change language settings and a Language window opens

5 - If 'English' is already on the list of languages, click the up arrow next to it to move it up to the 'default' position.

6 - If 'English' is not on the list, then in the Language window click on the blue 'Add another language'

7 - Scroll down to, and click on 'English' then click 'Select' in lower right corner

8 - Back at the Language window, click the up arrow next to your language to move it up to the default position.

9 - Refresh Google Drive